# winform application master form

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, master-pages

I was working on an application using asp.net and C# and It made it very easy to develop using the notion of Master Pages. 
now I am trying to develop a windows form application and I really need to have a master page here also. 
is there anything such as a master form ?

thank you

Comment: Create a template and derive the child pages from the template.

Comment: I think `winforms` is organized in a different way, you have to learn `winforms` from the basic concepts, there is less common thing between a desktop application and a web application.

Comment: raphsalands: can you give me a small example

Comment: @Raghubar is incorrect.  An Mdi form is simply a container for other winforms.  It is _not_ a template for other forms.  There are options, but nothing that provides exactly what a Master ASP page would provide, for instance.  We would have to know a lot more about your goals before knowing which option to recommend.

Comment: @YousifMohamed I strongly recommend WPF instead of winforms if you need such a thing. the WPF / XAML paradigm is much closer to the Web paradigm than the winforms one. Plus, winforms is a really outdated technology no longer recommended for any new projects, only to maintain legacy applications. (moderators: please don't ban me, I did not insult anyone here).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to simulate master-pages in winform you could cretae a base form, create either a class that inherits from System.windows.Forms or simply add a new form to your project, add the common controls and then create any other form adding an "Inherited Form" select the base form created and that should work

http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_inherited_forms.html

Answer (score 0):

There really isn't anything baked-in within Winform that works like ASP.NET master pages.

The closest you can get is having template forms with holes to be filled with user controls. You can connect your controls to "services" instances of the main form represented as interfaces types so that you can react on actions taken on controls owned by the template.

Be warned though, this isn't trivial and you're likely to face some unexpected limitations. Winform might not be the best platform for your new application because of that.